# Display JSON from sencha data store

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've searched and I can see this has been asked quite a few times, but I cant even figure out how to do a simple `console.log` on the data.

My store:

```
Ext.define('AventosPlanningTool.store.Aventos', {
  extend:'Ext.data.Store',

  config:
  {
    model:'AventosPlanningTool.model.Aventos',
    proxy:
    {
      type:'ajax',
      url:'resources/json/frames.json',
      reader:
      {
        type:'json',
        rootProperty:'options'
      }
    },
    autoLoad: true
  }
});
```

I can see in my network tab that the JSON file IS loading. I cannot figure out what to do with it at this point. In the data store, I've set the model to `AventosPlanningTool.model.Aventos` which is the file below.

```
Ext.define('AventosPlanningTool.model.Aventos', {
  extend:'Ext.data.Model',
  xtype:'AventosModel',

  config:
  {
    fields: [
      'name',
      'image'
    ]
  }
});
```

My JSON is pretty simple right now:

```
 {
  "name": "Cabinet Type",
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "Face Frame",
      "image": "resources/images/aventos/frames/faceframe.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Panel",
      "image": "resources/images/aventos/frames/panel.png"
    }   
  ]
}
```

Even if I can do a `console.log` on the data that would be very helpful. I can't figure out how to use the data. I've checked both guides in the docs: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/models, http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/stores and I just can't grasp it

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. You say the data loads, so what is the issue?

Comment: I don't know how to use the data once it is loaded, I don't know how to display it or even just a simple `console.log`

Comment: "Use" how? Are you binding it to a list? A view?

Comment: well the json is a title and an image so I assume it will be a custom "view" once I can figure out how to access the data

Comment: you still didn't get the answer you expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a load listener to your store:

```
Ext.define('AventosPlanningTool.store.Aventos', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model:'AventosPlanningTool.model.Aventos',
        proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            url:'resources/json/frames.json',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'options'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,

        listeners: {
            load: function(st, g, s, o, opts) {
                st.each(function(record) {
                    console.log(record.get('name') + ' - ' + record.get('image'));
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: there it is! This answered my original question, thanks. I can tell `st` means store and `opts` means options, but what is `g`, `s` and `o`?

Comment: records, succesful and operation as for: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load

Answer (score 1):

In sencha, data is defined in models, and actually memorized in stores. You can load your JSON through a proxy. Think of the model as the tables from sql and the store as the actual data in tables. Now, if you want to get the data from your store and perform operations on it, you have to load the store. To fetch your data into a list, you define a list with xtype:'list' specify your store store:'yourStoreName' and provide a template for showing that data. Here's a very detailed explanation on what I tried to say.

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store
also this:
http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the API docs for the data store. Note that you can only access the data once the store has been loaded. For example:

```
store.load();
store.getAt(0) // null, the store load hasn't completed yet.
```

You can loop over each record in the store using the `each` method. You can get a record at a particular index using `getAt`

```
store.each(function(rec) {
    console.log(rec.get('name'), rec.get('image'));
});

console.log(store.getAt(0).get('name'));
```

Often times you will bind the store to a list, there are plenty of examples of this in the API docs.

Comment: How do I know when the data has loaded then since I am using `autoload` and I am not tying the data to anything specific yet

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is to listen for the 'load' event on the store.

```
store.on('load', function(thisStore, records) {
   console.log(records[0].get('name'));
})
```